# Understanding Memory Allocation in Python

Tags: python

I'm really confused by the following code's output, that I am running on Ipython Notebook:

```
class Point(object):

   def __init(self, x=0, y=0):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   def __del__(self):
      class_name = self.__class__.__name__
      print class_name, "destroyed"

pt1 = Point()
pt2 = pt1
```

The output is as follows and I can't seem to understand when the destructor is called:
    Point destroyed

Also, then when I write the code below and expect to get an Error, I don't.

```
del pt1 
del pt2
```

Thanks

**Edit**: I understand that Python only calls `_del_()` when the reference count goes to 0, but what I don't understand is why writing the following results in the Output: `Point destroyed`.

```
pt1 = Point()
pt2 = pt1
```

Also, given the above, I know that either `pt1` or `pt2` doesn't exist and would thus expect an error in the below code, but that doesn't happen.

```
del pt1
del pt2
```

Comment: why do you expect an error?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've edited the question, which explains why I think there is an Error. I'm quite confused.

Comment: `pt1 = Point()pt2 = pt1` should not output anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume there is something regarding reference counting going on when multiple variables point to the same object. Look at the below example.

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = L1
```

Now let's look at our `id`s

```
>>> id(L1)
49127672

>>> id(L2)
49127672
```

So they point to the same `list` as expected.

```
del L1

>>> L2
[1, 2, 3]

>>> id(L2)
49127672
```

`L2` still exists and still has the same `id`, even though `L1` was deleted, which created the object in the first place.

So long story short, I think Python uses reference counting, and does not actually delete the object until the reference count drops to 0.

**Regarding your edit**

```
del pt1    # Reference count dropped from 2 to 1, __del__ is NOT called
del pt2    # Reference count dropped from 1 to 0, __del__ called
```

Note the output message "Point destroyed" is called because of `del pt2`, because `pt1` does not invoke this.

Answer (score 0):

as [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del_stmt) say:

*Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError exception will be raised.*

so you just remove two entries from local namespace, with each removal decreasing reference count by one. Only after ref count goes to zero, `__del__` is called. That's not C ;)